# JS: encapsulated foreach loop with arrays for JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I'm trying to get a foreach loop in a second one.
My code:

```
var results = data.d.results;
var boxes= [
   "Nmb1",
   "Nmb2",
   "Nmb3",
   "Nmb4",
   "Nmb5",
   ];

boxes.forEach(function(n){

  var boxesEach = results[0].n.results;                    

  boxesEach.forEach(function(i){
     $("input[value="+'"'+i+'"'+"]").attr('checked', true);
  });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to make for example "Nmb1" replacing the "n" which would make the following "output code":

```
var boxesEach = results[0].Nmb1.results;
```

It works if I just put the code like that but not with the loop.

Thanks for help and tips.

BTW: I'm getting the JSON via AJAX from a Sharepoint 2013 server (with the REST API).

Comment: BTW few things, you might want to use `results[0][n].results` instead of `results[0].n.results;`.

Comment: Sorry no demo because it's critical data.
That solution solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use it like an index. This is called the bracket notation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
var boxesEach = results[0][n].results;
```

The one you have right now tries to use a Dot notation for which you'd need the actual property name (i.e. Nmb1) and not a variable which holds the property name.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry! My bad. I just realized I was missing a .

Comment: Just figured it out myself, thank you very much for the fast solution though!